# Trying to set up a proxy server uisng nginx and docker

Tags: nginx, proxy, remote

I am trying to set up a proxy server to access a network. Currently there is a proxy server that people use securecrt to connect to and their web browser for some resources. I want to set up the server using docker so each person connecting to the proxy server gets a unique IP address that they access the network with instead of everyone coming from the same IP address. I am thinking of using nginx reverse proxy in a container so someone ssh to user1.proxy.domain.com and it forwards them to their proxy container and they can access the network from that container and set up their proxy on securecrt and then use the port set up in securecrt in their browser. I am having a hard time finding documentation on this as every time I search up proxy server it comes up with things like squid for setting up a caching proxy server for the internet and stuff. I don't mind doing the reading and research. I am looking to find some documentation for doing what I want though. Just looking for direction.

Comment: You'd better work with your network administrators to first decide what exactly is needed, a forward proxy or a reverse proxy, https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Well, network is all me. I know what needs to be accessed. I have set up a web server using the same idea. but I don't want to have web pages in this. I want people to be able to get to a server, like they do now, but I want that server to be in a container with it's own sshd server basically. I want minimal services and just have them be able to go to devices.

Comment: Proxies generally doesn't work that way They're application level devices, not layer 3. Why do every client need a distinct IP? That sounds like a silly requirement; as you control the proxy you can trust it. Make it strip any ` X-Forwarded-for` headers, and apply them. As you control the proxy, you can trust it.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong terminology. As Securecrt actually does the proxy part. I am trying to build a box where each user logging in has their own docker instance. This is for security and tracking.